# background only shows when selecting text - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, background, refresh

I'm having a strange issue I just can't get my head around. On firefox and IE, my footer's background image displays fine, but on chrome, it only shows up when I start selecting the footer text, or when I refresh the page.

Here's the website:
www.josephviatte.com

here's the footer's CSS:

```
.site-footer {
  background-color: #660000;
  background-image: url("http://josephviatte.com/wp-content/uploads/manual-uploads/footer-bg.jpg");
  color: white;
  height: 260px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-size: 100% 260px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but I found something wrong:

```
    .site-footer {
  background-color: background-color: #660000;
```

this is invalid.

Comment: thank you! That does solve half the problem. My background image still doesn't show up, but now at least I don't find myself with white text over a white background.

Comment: Thanks .You can always use chrome inspect element from the right click context, then turn on and off css properties for specific classes.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I decided to remove
    background-attachment: fixed;

Of course, my background is a little sadder now that it scrolls, but at least it displays. Chrome seems to have something against fixed backgrounds...